# Designing customer portal database schema

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to create a database schema with the following requirements:

(1) One table for recording the customer database, username, password, address, etc.

(2) Each customer has a time-series data unique to his account.

Now I'm facing an decision in database schema:
(i) should the schema be designed such that all time series data to be housed under one single table (it will be gigantic, considering the number of customers x number of data), with a foreign key from the customer data
(ii) or should the schema be designed such that each customer has a FK with unique customerID, and this customerId is used as part of the table name (like "[CustomerID]_Data").

Or is there better ways of managing the customer time series data? Currently looking at 1000 data points per customer per day, for 50,000 customers.

Comment: (ii) is a terrible idea. (i) may need some support in the form of partitioning but essentially seems like the way to go

Comment: I suspect that if you have 50,000 customers, you can afford professional help!